# get the vertical length of Url Image in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have url Image address.

I want to get the vertical value of the image without downloading the url image.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return photos[indexPath.item].image.size.height
}
```

I will set the length of the Cell to the value obtained.

Please help me.

Comment: There's no feasible, non-hacky way of obtaining image properties without having the entire file unless there's another way the server can supply you with those properties.

Comment: Unfortunately, thank you very much!

Comment: Try this.
if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url! as CFURL, nil) {
     if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary? {
          let pixelWidth = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as! Int
          let pixelHeight = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as! Int
          print("the image width is: \(pixelWidth)")
          print("the image height is: \(pixelHeight)")
       }
   }

Comment: It worked, but it also works very well. Thank you.